# How To Select an Array Using GORM Raw in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, struct, go-gorm

I receive this error on my app log:

```
[error] unsupported data type: &[]
```

What I'm trying to do is to run a `SELECT` query to a many-to-many data using `json_agg()` where the data type in the struct that I'm using is `[]string`

this is the `GetArticleById` Struct

```
type GetArticleByID struct{
    ID              string          `json:"article_id" gorm:"column:article_id"`
    Title           string          `json:"title"`
    Content         string          `json:"content"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    Author          string          `json:"author"`
    Category        string          `json:"category"`
    SubCategory     string          `json:"sub_category"`
    Keywords        []string        `json:"keywords"`
    Unit            string          `json:"unit"`
}
```

and this is the Query execution

```
query := `SELECT 
                a.article_id, a.title, a.created_at, a.content, u.name AS author, c.name AS category, sc.name AS sub_category,
                json_agg(k.name) AS keywords, unit.name AS unit
            FROM 
                articles a
                LEFT JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
                LEFT JOIN categories c ON a.category_id = c.categ_id
                LEFT JOIN sub_categories sc ON a.sub_category_id = sc.sub_categ_id
                LEFT JOIN article_keywords ak ON a.article_id = ak.article_refer_id
                LEFT JOIN keywords k ON ak.keyword_refer_id = k.keyword_id
                LEFT JOIN units unit ON a.unit_id = unit.unit_id
            WHERE 
                a.article_id = ? AND
                a.is_posted = true
            GROUP BY 
                a.article_id, u.name, c.name, sc.name, unit.name`

    err := db.Raw(query, id).Scan(&article).Error
```

I want to use Raw SQL instead of ORM because this is for a project and I want to test out the comparison of Raw SQL and ORM.

Comment: Questions: What datatype does `article` have? Since there should be multiple rows returned, shouldn't the code iterate the rows and then scan each one of them into article?

Comment: Don't you need to indicate `gorm:"serializer:json` for `keywords`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by adding a gorm serializer tag on the `GetArticleById` struct for `Keywords`

```
type GetArticleByID struct {
    ID          string    `json:"article_id" gorm:"column:article_id"`
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    Content     string    `json:"content"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    Author      string    `json:"author"`
    Category    string    `json:"category"`
    SubCategory string    `json:"sub_category"`
    Keywords    []string  `json:"keywords" gorm:"serializer:json"`
    Unit        string    `json:"unit"`
}
```